# failure delivering result resultinfo who=null request=4001 result=-1 data=null

Tags: java, android, exception

I get an error `failure delivering result resultinfo who=null request=4001 result=-1 data=null` on below line of code :

```
String matchString = gson.toJson(userMatches);
```

Where `userMatches` is a custom object and has

`ArrayList<RS_SingleMatch> arrayOfMatches;` where again `RS_SingleMatch` is a custom object object and that has primary variables. Both custom objects are `Parcelable`.

**Logcat :**

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What userMatches object contains?

Comment: @Sandy Please look at edited question.

Comment: Can you please post, what userMachets object contains?

Comment: @Sandy Actually it parcelable so have methods for that. Otherwise only 2 variables. `private ArrayList<RS_SingleMatch> arrayOfMatches;` and 
 `private Context context;`. Posting whole class here would be a mess. I can mail to you if you don't mind.