# Saving an ArrayList of custom objects in internal storage

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of RowItem where RowItem Class have following variables :

```
public class RowItem
{
   private Bitmap photo;
   private String photoURL ;
   private int online_status;
   private String name;
   private String last_seen;
   private int delete;
   //Getters and Setters ...
}
```

I want to save this ArrayList into internal storage. Here is the list of things I have already tried but aren't working :

1. Implemented exclusion strategy as indicated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296404/save-custom-object-in-shared-preferences). Excluded Bitmap from saving as I am Lazy Loading Images From URLs to ListView. But I am still getting errors like :

   ```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.awesome.clique/com.awesome.clique.Home}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.text.BoringLayout declares multiple JSON fields named mPaint.
   ```

   If I am saving in onPause() or onStop() using SharedPreferences(using gson) or Files.
2. Overridden methods of readObject and writeObject for RowIem class. But it still kept on giving the above error.

Now I am out of options now. I do now think that saving the ArrayList in SQLite database maybe feasible, but I do not know how to save this list into SQLite databse as I have no idea about SQLite and in a glance it seemed very complex. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), it will simplify how you work with SQLite.

Take a look at how I implemented a simple model here: https://github.com/slidese/BabyFeed/blob/master/src/se/slide/babyfeed/model/FeedLog.java

And have a look (at that same project) how you work with it, it pretty simple.

Your code would look something like this:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class RowItem
{
   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
   private int id;

   @DatabaseField
   private Bitmap photo;

   @DatabaseField
   private String photoURL;

   @DatabaseField
   private int online_status;

   @DatabaseField
   private String name;

   @DatabaseField
   private String last_seen;

   @DatabaseField
   private int delete;

   //Getters and Setters ...
}
```

And then:

```
DatabaseManager.getInstance().addRowItem(row);
```

You create these helper methods, for example a delete could look like this:

```
public void deleteRowItem(RowItem row) {
    try {
        getHelper().getRowDao().delete(row);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me , how will I delete a particular row ?

Comment: It's a bit too much code to paste here. But you could look at how I'm working with it in the DatabaseManager and DatabaseHelper classes here: https://github.com/slidese/BabyFeed/blob/master/src/se/slide/babyfeed/db/DatabaseManager.java

Comment: In your code there is a function for adding FeedLogs, its okay but I am a little puzzled that how will I delete a particular FeedLog or RowItem ? If you could just paste the function for delete only, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @SlashGeek I added a delete helper method to the answer.

Comment: Hey I am getting a NullPointerException along with the following warnings : ": unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao;) VFY: unable to resolve interface method: Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao;.create (Ljava/lang/Object;)I". What is happening ?

Comment: Have you added the ORMLite jar files to your project?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42739/discussion-between-slashgeek-and-mike)

Comment: Sorry, I need to leave in a few minutes. Please have a look at the ORMLite page for the jar files you need and look how I implemented it in my app.

Comment: This line : listItems = (ArrayList<RowItem>)DatabaseManager.getInstance().getAllRowItems(); is  throwing NullPointerException , and I can't find out why. Although the warnings are not showing up as I have also added ORMLite-core-4.47.jar to the project.

Comment: Hey I got the bug,the getInstance() was the convict. It was just returning the instance without checking it was null or not. Thanks anyways :)